# How do I find the type of a value in C++?

Tags: python, c++

How can I find the type of value in C++? i.e. What is C++'s equivalent of Python's `type()`?

Comment: C++ is statically typed, it works fundamentally different from Python. As a consequence, there simply isn’t a direct equivalent of Python’s `type` function, and you’ll need to provide more detail about your use-case to make your question answerable.

Comment: [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) if you need the type (i.e. to create another variable of that type). [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) if you want a name (but the name will be mangled, it's not going to be a nice readable name).

Comment: Usually, you know the type because you wrote it. `int i = 5;` <- type is `int`, no function needed. Can you explain why you need to use `type`?

Comment: @user253751 _Usually, you know the type because you wrote it_ -- not if you use `auto`.

Answer (score 2):

`decltype(value)` is one way, where `value` is the variable name.

Prior to C++11, you needed to use template metaprogramming.

Comment: Of course, it won’t tell you the dynamic type, just the static type. I can’t think of a situation in which you’d use `decltype` in the same way as Python’s `type`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [typeid operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/typeid-operator?view=vs-2019).

```
#include <typeinfo>
...
cout << typeid(variable).name() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `typeid` operator should be the closest feature. It examines the dynamic type, so it's suitable for polymorphic types but not suitable for templates.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct MyStructA {};
struct MyStructB: MyStructA {};

int main() {
    MyStructA* b = new MyStructB;
    auto&& type = typeid(*b); // "type" is your type
    std::cout << type.name(); // print its name
    return 0;
}
```

The output is not guaranteed to be anything in particular, except it can be used to identify the type. It's usually a mangled name of the type, so maybe not ideal.